# How can I "group by" cell value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which look like:

```
_|a |b |c
x|1 |1 |1
y|2 |2 |3
z|3 |2 |1
```

I want the result to be:

```
{
    1: [(x,a),(x,b),(x,c),(z,c)}
    2: [(y,a),(y,b),(z,b)]
    3: [(y,c),(z,a)]
}
```

I dont care if the result is a dictionary or another dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.groups` here

```
g = df.stack()
g.groupby(g).groups
{
  1: [('x', 'a'), ('x', 'b'), ('x', 'c'), ('z', 'c')], 
  2: [('y', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'b')], 
  3: [('y', 'c'), ('z', 'a')]
}
```

Comment: Nice idea with groups..Happy holidays! stay safe and healthy :)

Comment: Thank you...Happy holidays and Merry Christmas...TBH I first tried the same approach as yours(upvoted) then moved onto using groups. :P

Answer (score 4):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the dataframe then use `groupby` inside a `dict` comprehension to create key-value pairs correspoding to cell value and index:

```
s = df.stack()
dct = {k: [*g.index] for k, g in s.groupby(s)}
```

---

```
{1: [('x', 'a'), ('x', 'b'), ('x', 'c'), ('z', 'c')],
 2: [('y', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'b')],
 3: [('y', 'c'), ('z', 'a')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
#Dummy example - 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1],'B':[1,1,3,2]}, index=['x','y','z','w'])

#Create tuples of value, index and column
l = [(i,(j,k)) for k,v in df.items() for i,j in zip(v,v.index)]

#Group them by value and create list
pd.DataFrame(l).groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
```

```
0
1    [(x, A), (w, A), (x, B), (y, B)]
2                    [(y, A), (w, B)]
3                    [(z, A), (z, B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice answers here, I chose to use `melt`, I'm adding this as perhaps it's useful to see / perhaps there are mistakes in this which others should avoid and someone will highlight.

Here's an approach though:

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": [1, 2, 2],
        "c": [1, 3, 1],
    },
    index=list("xyz"),
)
```

```py
cell_values = {}
for cell_value, g in df.reset_index().melt(id_vars="index").groupby("value"):
    cell_values[cell_value] = set(g[["index", "variable"]].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

I've assumed that only unique entries were wanted, and have used `set()` as a result.